# Resolve root folder in other folder without edit URL client

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to resolve my root folder public_html (`www.example.com`) to another folder (`www.example.com/laravel/public/`) without editing the client URL.

I tried this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://www.mysite.lol/laravel/public/ [R=301,L]
```

This `.htaccess` file edits the client URL, and looks like this:

```
https://www.example.com/laravel/public/
```

Any ideas?

EDIT:

Thanks for your answer Señor White:

Now the response is 404, my apache_error.log has logged this:

```
[Fri Aug 31 13:18:35.427305 2018] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 4544:tid 1992] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 127.0.0.1:52310] 127.0.0.1 - - [spotlike.plain/sid#2534f80][rid#256e1c0/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/repositorios/mysite/] applying pattern '^laravel/public/' to uri ''
[Fri Aug 31 13:18:35.427305 2018] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 4544:tid 1992] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client 127.0.0.1:52310] 127.0.0.1 - - [mysite.plain/sid#2534f80][rid#256e1c0/initial] [perdir C:/xampp/htdocs/repositorios/mysite/] rewrite '' -> '/laravel/public/repositorios/mysite/'
```

Edit 2

Inside laravel/public exists a .htaccess file, this look like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

EDIT 3

I can solved the internal redirect, in other answer of MrWhite haha

```
RewriteRule .* laravel/public/ [L]
```

But i lost all assets, the site try to find the files in the root folder, example:

https://website.lol/landing/img/logos-web/Samsung.png

(/landing, is a asset folder inside the folder /laravel)

Comment: This is presumably the `.htaccess` file in the document root of your site? Do you have any other directives in your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: The .htaccess is located in my root folder and have not more directives. Laravel have a htaccess, but its for internal use in the framework, this havent directives to redirect o rewrite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need an *internal rewrite*, as opposed to an *external redirect*, which is what you currently have (although also incorrect since it redirects everything to your home page).

Try something like the following instead of your current `RewriteRule` directive:

```
RewriteRule !^laravel/public/ /laravel/public%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

And make sure you clear your browser cache before testing.

Comment: I create a new response to you can see better my message. Thanks for your response! :)

Comment: Does it work if you request `/laravel/public/foo` directly? (`foo` being any valid URL.)